# Detect useragent before sending mail

Tags: newsletter, ezpublish

Can someone tell me if it is possible to send different kinds of templates as newsletter according to its receiver's browser(mobile or web)?
Can i do a test on the navigator before sending?

@thanx

Comment: So you would like your e-mail program, installed on your computer to check what browser is installed on other people computers (that could also be possibly turned off and plugged-off at the time of sending your e-mail)..? How would you imagine this to be possible?!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you concern is compatibility with different clients. The best you can do is to keep your newsletter template simple and table based.

You can also use newsletter frameworks like Zurb Ink http://zurb.com/ink/

and testing tools like litmus https://litmus.com/